# Can't retrieve more than 2 gmail messages using Zend framework imap access - server dies - doens't report any error

Tags: php, zend-framework, gmail, google-apps, zend-mail

Hi guys I'm working on a google apps application. Basically I've set it up so users can add multiple gmail addresses and check on their inboxes in the application. It works fine with a google apps email address however when I add a gmail address it just dies out.

I'm using this code here:

```
$mail = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($mail_options);

$all_messages = array();

$page = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1;
$limit = isset($_GET['limit'])?$_GET['limit']:20;

$offset = (($page-1)*$limit)+1;

$end = ($page*$limit)>$c?$c:($page*$limit);
for ($i=$offset;$i<=$end;$i++){

    $h2t = new html2text();
    $h2t->set_allowed_tags('<a>');

    if(!$mail[$i])
        break;
    else{
        $one_message = $mail->getMessage($i);
        $one_message->id = $i;
        $one_message->UID = $mail->getUniqueId($i);

        $one_message->parts = array();
        $one_message->body = '';
        $count = 1;
        foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($mail->getMessage($i)) as $ii=>$part) {

            try {
                $tpart = $part;
                //$tpart->_content = '';
                $one_message->parts[$count] =  $tpart;
                $count++;
                // check for html body
                if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/html') {
                    $b = $part->getContent();

                    if($part->contentTransferEncoding == 'quoted-printable')
                        $b = quoted_printable_decode($b);

                    $one_message->html_body = $b;
                    $h2t->set_html($b);
                    $one_message->body = $h2t->get_text();
                }

                //check for text body

                if (strtok($part->contentType, ';') == 'text/plain') {
                    $b = $part->getContent();

                    if($part->contentTransferEncoding == 'quoted-printable')
                        $b = quoted_printable_decode($b);

                    $one_message->text_body = $b;

                    $one_message->body = $b;//$part->getContent();
                }

            } catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e) {
                // ignore
            }

        }

        $all_messages[] = $one_message;

    }
}
```

No matter what the emails it dies out on retrieving just 2 emails... whats going on here?

Comment: What setting do you have for your $mail_options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are catching the exception log it some where for just do a var_dump, Going through the exception will help to find out the issue easily. Also you can post the exception message here without it answering this question is difficult.

Comment: Its not giving any exception at all which is very strange - I have no idea what to look for in this case...what could be the problem.

Comment: @Ali it isn't strange that you're not seeing an exception since you are catching Zend_Mail_Exception and ignoring it.  Try putting the code outside of the try {} catch block and then you may well see some exceptions!

Comment: Dang I found out where the issue was - in one of the many umpteen files I was including there was an ini_set command resetting to hide error reporting - errors were being reported prior to the inclusion of that file... got it figured out now...